# Prove Convergence in Probability of $\frac{x_n}{n}$ where $x_n$ = {# of times in Bernoulli RV that success is followed by failure}

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have IID Bernoulli trials with $p=1/3$. Let $x_n = ${number of times in the first n trials that a success is followed by a failure}. Prove that $\frac{x_n}{n}$ converges in probability to $\frac{2}{9}$.

This is the first probability convergence problem I have come across and I am struggling with where to begin. My first that was to use the weak law of large numbers. But I am not sure how to apply it here because technically the sequence of interest is not Bernoulli.

Can you get me started?

Comment: You could potentially use a discrete time Markov chain with 2-element state space $\{S, F\}$, or if you prefer, 4-element state space $\{SS, SF, FS, FF\}$. Alternatively, if you know the bounded sequence $X_n/n$ converges in probability then you can take expectations $E[X_n]/n$ to find out what it converges to. [From this you will find it converges to $2/9$ instead of $1/9$.]

Comment: *Hint* you can try to obtain recurrence relation on $x_n$. The answer will depend on last two digits. So I guess it will be not so hard to do it.

Comment: @openspace : $X_n$ is a random process that satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n=\infty$ with prob 1, I don't think it makes sense to define a recurrence relation for $X_n$.  It may make sense to define recurrence relations on probabilities of certain events, or perhaps on certain expectations, although here we want to understand the sample average $X_n/n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Michael  = What if we defined $T_i$= T{ith trial is a success and (i+1) trial is a failure}. Then $X_n= \sum_{i}^{n-1}T_n$. Could I use this to prove what I need?

Comment: That indicator function approach is the best way to compute $E[X_n]$.

Comment: If you have time, can you explain to me if/how that would help me prove. $\frac{x_n}{n}$ converges in probability to $\frac{2}{9}$?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach you can follow (there are still computations to do):

#### Expectations:

You can compute $E[\frac{X_n}{n}]$ very easily via the indicator function approach that you mentioned.

Since $0 \leq \frac{X_n}{n} \leq 1$ for all $n$, if $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges to some constant $c$ with probability 1 (or even in the weaker sense "in probability") then $E[\frac{X_n}{n}]$ must also converge to $c$.  You can justify this, for example, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem and/or the "bounded convergence theorem."

#### DTMC

If we define a Discrete Time Markov Chain (DTMC) with state space $\{SS, SF, FS, FF\}$, where the state represents the history of the past two trials, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{X_n}{n}$ is the same as the fraction of time we are in state $SF$. We know by steady state theory that this fraction of time converges to some steady state value $\pi(SF)$ with probability 1 (regardless of the initial state).

So you can either compute the steady state of this 4-state DTMC directly, or you can use the fact that steady state exists, and so $\frac{X_n}{n}\rightarrow c$ with probability 1 for some constant $c$, then compute $c$ by $c=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[\frac{X_n}{n}]$.

Comment: Thank you so much. And I appreciate that you didn't solve the whole thing out as I would prefer to work on it myself anyway :)